# Wrong hour of day in Java calendar

Tags: java

```
TimeZone zone1 = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York");
TimeZone zone2 = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Istanbul");
int hour1 = Calendar.getInstance(zone1).get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int hour2 = Calendar.getInstance(zone2).get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

// hour1 gives 1
// hour2 gives 7
```

Right now it is 1 at New York, but 8 at Istanbul. Why does Java give 1 less result for Europe/Istanbul? Can it be because of daylight savings? If so, doesn't it take care of it automatically?

I am not sure if the problem is because of daylight savings thing. The following shows, I guess, both timezones have DST offset:

```
zone1.getDSTSavings()/1000L   // gives 3600
zone2.getDSTSavings()/1000L   // gives 3600

zone1.useDaylightTime()   // true
zone2.useDaylightTime()   // true

zone1.inDaylightTime(new Date())   // false
zone2.inDaylightTime(new Date())   // false
```

**SOLVED:**

Time zone data was not up to date. Download the tzupdater utility from Java website, and issue:

```
java -jar tzupdater.jar -l 'http://www.iana.org/time-zones/repository/tzdata-latest.tar.gz'
```

This auto downloads the latest tz data and updates the JRE. This is a hell. Losing 2 days for a stupid timezone problem. This should be automated and the JRE should self update every day. Why not???

Insert new crontab entry: (Yet another one)

```
crontab -e
00 05 * * * java -jar tzupdater.jar -l https://www.iana.org/time-zones/repository/tzdata-latest.tar.gz
```

Comment: This post might be helpful:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13611108/problems-with-java-daylight-savings-time

Comment: Can you try the below mentioned code and let me know                                TimeZone zone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York");
DateFormat format = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
format.setTimeZone(zone);

System.out.println(format.format(new Date()));

Answer (score 7):

There seems to be problems with Turkey time as turkey has changed there DST from 
[1 Nov to 8 Nov](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-34631326)

because for the un-updated JVM if i do

```
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Istanbul");
System.out.println(timeZone.inDaylightTime(new Date()))
```

It gives me False but as for Istanbul the DST is till NOV 8.

So you need to update the JVM `tzdata` version from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzdata-versions-138805.html). Here is what Latest tzdata Data version also says.

> tzdata2015g  n/a Turkey's 2015 fall-back transition is scheduled for
>   Nov. 8, not Oct. 25. Norfolk moves from +1130 to +1100 on 2015-10-04
>   at 02:00 local time.  Fiji's 2016 fall-back transition is scheduled
>   for January 17, not 24. Fort Nelson, British Columbia will not fall
>   back on 2015-11-01. It has effectively been on MST (-0700) since it
>   advanced its clocks on 2015-03-08. New zone America/Fort_Nelson.

So Refer to this tzupdater [documents](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/tzupdater-readme-136440.html#ondemand) to get update for your JVM

Answer (score 2):

This code is correct. My result New York 1 - Istanbul 9.
This problem is your computer or OS. I live in Istanbul and hour of day 9.
Summer time application is not over. Because the Turkish elections were postponed for 2 weeks.

```
    TimeZone zone1 = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York");
    TimeZone zone2 = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Istanbul");
    int hour1 = Calendar.getInstance(zone1).get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int hour2 = Calendar.getInstance(zone2).get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

    System.out.println("New York" + hour1 + " - Istanbul "+ hour2);
```